# Will Slf4j annotation work in Grails?

Tags: grails, logging, groovy, log4j, slf4j

I have a Groovy library that logs using the `@Slf4j` annotation provided by Groovy:

```
@Slf4j
class SomePogo {
    // do stuff
}
```

If I drop this lib into a Grails (2.4.2) application, will the default log4j-based logging system pick up the log statements in these classes? Or do I need to add log4j loggers to all my classes?

Answer (score 8):

All Grails artefacts (controllers, domain classes, taglibs, services, etc.) have a static logger field (named `log`) added to them automatically.

Classes in `src/groovy` also have a logger field named `log` added to them automatically, but in this case, the logger is non-static. Therefore, the only time you'll need to explicitly add a logger is if you want to log something *statically* from a `src/groovy` class. In such a case, you'll need to annotate the class `@Slf4j` (or `@Log4j`) in order to replace the non-static logger added by Grails with a static `log` field.

Comment: All Groovy classes get loggers, even `src/groovy`

Comment: @Dónal - the question is about a 3rd party JAR added to the Grails app as a dependency. If its classes are annotated with `@Slf4j`, will its loggers get picked up by Grails?

Comment: @IAmYourFaja yes, of course. Log4J has no idea which classes are "yours", and which belong to 3rd party libs, so it treats them all the same.

Comment: @BurtBeckwith it appears the loggers added to classes in `src/groovy` are non-static. I've updated my answer with this info

Comment: Another benefit of adding your own loggers (esp in artifacts) is to control the logger name - I always forget the convention for artifacts, and prefer to just use full class name + package, so I usually add `static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this)` or `protected final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass().name)` and then I know that all of my loggers are under `com.burtbeckwith.appname`/`grails.plugin.pluginname`/etc.